# ActiveRecord and loading data from related tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model looks like this (example):

```
class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :currencies
  # other stuff
end
```

When I want to get some bank from database i do:

```
bank = Bank.first :joins => :some_table,
         :conditions => {
           #some conditions
         }
```

Now, is there any way to **explicitly** retrieve currencies from database for provided conditions and sort them in some order and store them in *bank.currencies* ?

I'm doing something like this:

```
bank.currencies.reject! { |c| c.value < something }
bank.currencies.sort! { |x,y| x.value <=> y.value }
```

It works but this way I retrieve all records and filter them by myself.
I would like to have DBMS do it for me.

This is just an example with banks and currencies. I have some big records and I think it is important just to retrieve those which interest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can issue "find" clauses on the relationship, like this:

```
bank.currencies.find(:all, :conditions => {something}, :order => {something})
```

or, if you prefer:

```
bank.currencies.all(:conditions => {something}, :order => {something})
```

All the standard ActiveRecord options should be available - e.g. limit, order etc.

Of course, if you find yourself re-using the query logic, you can declare named scopes on the Currency model - say, 'with_count_greater_than' and 'in_order' - and then chain them together:

```
bank.currencies.with_count_greater_than(10).in_order
```

You may also want to investigate [SearchLogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic), which implements many useful named scopes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you?

```
bank = Bank.first
concurrencies = Concurrency.find(:all, :conditions => {:bank => bank}, :order => "position desc")
```

Or you could change your bank model

```
def Bank << AR
  has_many :concurrencies

  def ordered_concurrencies
    Concurrency.for_bank(self)
  end
end

def Concurrency << AR
  belongs_to :bank

  named_scope :for_bank, lambda { |*args| {:conditions => {:bank => args.first}, :order => "position desc"} }
end
```

So you could call

```
Bank.first.ordered_concurrencies
```

and get the ordered concurrencies as ActiveRecord-Collection.

Beside this, with this solution you can add other conditions as well:

```
Bank.first.ordered_concurrencies.find(:all, :conditions => ["name like ?", "Dollar"])
```